# Issue when switch language in springMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

i am working with spring mvc, i am using tomcat 9 to deploy my webapp, everything working fine on window 10, but when deploying on window server 2016 japanese i have an issue, LocaleResolver is not working, i can't switch between japanese and english language.
Here is configuration on my code:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver _resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    _resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return _resolver;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor _interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    _interceptor.setParamName(Constants.SESS_LOCALE);
    registry.addInterceptor(_interceptor);
}
```

in jsp i am using spring taglib to display:

```
<spring:message code="login.userid" />
```

Who have experience on this please help me or do you have any suggestion?
Thank you very much.

Comment: which spring version are you using?Try to add the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` flag in your xml file

Comment: i am using spring version 5.0.5, let me try your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: I have already used @EnableWebMvc

Comment: Maybe you need to add more of your code so that others can analysis it